# Two models of $BT^n$

Tags: algebraic-topology, classifying-spaces

Let $T^n$ be the $n$-torus. We have (at least) two nice models of the classifying space $BT^n$:

1. $(\mathbb{CP}^\infty)^n$;
2. The flag manifold $F_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)=V_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)/T^n$, where $V_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)$ is the Stiefel manifold of orthonormal $n$-frames  in $\mathbb{C}^\infty$.

As the inclusion $V_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)\subset (S^\infty)^n$ is $T^n$-equivariant, it induces an inclusion $F_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)\subset(\mathbb{CP}^\infty)^n$. The universal property of classifying spaces show that this inclusion is a homotopy equivalence. As it is also a (closed Hurewicz) cofibration, it follows that $F_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)$ is a deformation retract of $(\mathbb{CP}^\infty)^n$. However, I don't see how $(\mathbb{CP}^\infty)^n$ even retracts onto $F_n(\mathbb{C}^\infty)$.

So my question is: ***Is there a nice description of a deformation retraction?***

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the idea is to homotope $\Bbb C P^\infty\times\Bbb C P^\infty$, for example, so that the first $\Bbb C P^\infty$ consists of lines in $\Bbb C\times\{0\}\times\Bbb C\times\{0\}\times\cdots$ and the second $\Bbb C P^\infty$ has lines in $\{0\}\times\Bbb C\times\{0\}\times\Bbb C\times\cdots$. Then we can think of points in $\Bbb C P^\infty\times\Bbb C P^\infty$ as pairs of lines in one big $\Bbb C^\infty$, and those lines are automatically orthogonal.

Comment: Aha! That's clever. That will gives us an inverse homotopy equivalence. But I believe that the resulting map is not a retraction.